# how to differentiate Normal logs and auditing logs in logstash filter, if the input is same?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I have an application running in Kubernetes. And I have two types of logs,

1. Normal logs
2. auditing logs

For example,

Following is the example of a single log file which has both kind of data, normal logs and auditing

```
[INFO] [] [%{TraceId}] 2021-10-02_18:37:01.601 com.MyExample.Test Getting app config from Config server with Base URL BASE_URL for application.
[INFO] [] [%{TraceId}] 2021-10-02_18:25:11.807 Audit Hello world,test file,123454,123Addb,true
```

In the above example, the first line is a normal log and the second log is audit data.

**I want both of these logs to go to different indices (2 different index) and I want to apply a different kind of logstash filter for both the logs.**

Any suggestion on how I can solve the above problem?

Also adding a flow diagram of requirement:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faWZ9.jpg)

My current **logstash.conf** file serves only auditing purposes and I am using a .csv file

```
input {
  file {
    path => "<path_to_dir>/audit-*.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      skip_header => "false"
      columns => ["TraceId","timestamp","fcId","Ean","source","Quantity","updateSent","message"]
  }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
     index => "audit"
  }
stdout {}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please update your questions with details such as that you're getting all events on the same input and your main question is how to differentiate those two type of logs in filter. Add more details if you have any.

Comment: And I'm afraid that we'll need more examples of logs so we can see what is the pattern, if there is anything besides key value pattern that makes difference.

Comment: @Filip I have updated the question, tried to make it as descriptive as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is not very clean, but right now I don't see other way to do it if there is no label saying `audit` or `log`.

You can try to match `JAVACLASS`, [which is part of logstash core](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/ecs-v1/java), with `grok`, probably you are about to use `grok` anyways later to analyze your log. Grok can [tag](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-tag_on_failure) events with `_grokparsefailure` in case there is no match in audit logs and from what you said, there shouldn't be. After `grok` just use `if` and check if the tag is present, if it is, then it's audit log, otherwise it's basic log and then process your events as you please.

For `JAVACLASS` pattern to work inside of `grok`, you will need to set `ecs_compatibility` to `v1` as explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-ecs_compatibility).

Disclaimer, this is idea based on only 2 examples you provided, this could be completely wrong, in that case please provide more examples, because without clear pattern it's impossible to come up with the solution.

Concrete example:

Log line

```
[INFO] [] [123trace456] 2021-10-02_18:37:01.601 com.MyExample.Test Getting app config from Config server with Base URL BASE_URL for application.
```

Grok pattern

```
\[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\] \[\] \[(?<traceId>[0-9a-z]*)\] (?<timestamp>[0-9\-_:\.]*) %{JAVACLASS:class} %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

Result

```
{
  "loglevel": [
    [
      "INFO"
    ]
  ],
  "traceId": [
    [
      "123trace456"
    ]
  ],
  "timestamp": [
    [
      "2021-10-02_18:37:01.601"
    ]
  ],
  "class": [
    [
      "com.MyExample.Test"
    ]
  ],
  "message": [
    [
      "Getting app config from Config server with Base URL BASE_URL for application."
    ]
  ]
}
```

I have no idea what kind of timestamp that is and how your trace ID looks like so I just did whatever, the point is the usage of `JAVACLASS` pattern. I found plenty of examples by googling, please don't forget, google is your friend!

Comment: The only way we can differentiate between them is by using the class name. For normal logs, we have the normal class name, but for audit, we have the class name as "audit". It would be a great help if you could add a simple implementation of "JAVACLASS" in logstash.conf file, so I can use it as a reference.

Comment: Here you go, please use google a bit more.